# makefile, missing separator error

Tags: c++, g++, makefile, cygwin

I written a very simple `makefile` for a `c++` program, but it returns `makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.` error. What's wrong with it?

`makefile`:

```
all:
[tab]g++ function.cpp -o out
```

I compile the program in `cygwin` and `Ubuntu`.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you really want to pass `function.h` on the command line? That seems *quite* unusual.

Answer (score 9):

You need a real tab instead of space in front of g++ command, also you don't need to put `function.h` in g++ command.

```
all:
    g++ function.cpp  -o out
^^^ tab here
```

Comment: I applied your recommendation, but nothing happened.

Comment: How did you add tab in front of g++?

Comment: I am not very familiar with stackoverflow so used [tab] to indicate that I used tab in this place.

Comment: If there is only one tab between g++, it should work. what happens if you just run `g++ function.cpp  -o out` command on console?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 4 (8?) spaces, use `<tab>` at the beginning of the second line.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), the most common cause for this error is that lines are indented with whitespaces when `make` expects tab characters.

Answer (score 2):

The second line must start with a tab.

The first line is target, then you define rules below target. Rule lines must all start with tab.

Comment: I beat 5 seconds to you! :P